# Background image no longer filling screen

Tags: css, background-image

This question was originally asked over at Wordpress Development but as it concerns a more generic CSS issue I was asked to post it here instead. That thread, and initial explanation, [can be seen here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161990/background-image-no-longer-filling-screen/162019#162019).

---

I have a `background-size: cover` image set as the header of single posts which used to fill the screen, with content beginning immediately below. For some reason, it no longer does this. The background image itself *is* scaling to fit the screen, but the content below it (the text of the post) is beginning immediately after the overlaid text.

You can see what I mean [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vn668fLL/1).

If I set `#hero-header` to `position:absolute; min-height: 100%; min-width:100%;` then the image does fill the screen when you load the page. The problem then is that the content below it runs over the top, rather than beginning just off screen.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

---

To clarify what I mean by 'fill the screen', following a response below:

The div that contains the background image should fill the entire screen when you load it. At the moment the background image is scaling to fit the screen, but `#hero-header` is not forcing the content below it off the page – it is falling after the text element, `.hero-text`, within it instead.

Answer (score 0):

This has fixed the problem:

Background image moved to `html` and `#hero-header` set to `height: 100vh`.